# Overlaying multiple PNG images

Tags: css

Good evening.  My problem is this:

I am rendering information on extrasolar planets from a database.  When queried (PHP/MySQL), each planet renders as a .png based on its type and is given a height and width depending on its size (max of 150px), and is centered within a table cell.  What I want to do is to overlay multiple .pngs for clouds and other textures, which would be the same size and also centered within the table cell.

http://w.tarazedi.com/image1100 is an image of the problem.

I know how I would do this with absolute positioning and z-index if the page were static, but do not know how to do it with dynamic content.  Also I do not know how to do it as a generic property (rather than having a CSS definition for each rendered planet).

Answer (score 6):

The process'd be the same whether it's static or dynamic... wrap each planet base image in a container, the position your overlays relative to that, e.g.

```
<div class="planetimage">
   <img src="baseimage.png" class="base" />
   <img src="clouds.png" class="overlay" style="z-index: 1" />
   <img src="othertexture.png" class="overlay" style="z-index: 2" />
</div>

.planetimage {
    position: relative;
}

.planetimage .base {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   z-index : 0;
}

.planetimage .overlay{
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
}
```

The only thing you'd have to keep track of is the z-index for each additional overlay you add, so they properly stack on top of each other.

Comment: also, one of your css selectors should be `.planetimage .overlay`

Comment: the base image should not be absolute, otherwise the container will not have the correct size

Answer (score 0):

See if you can place each planet in a div with the same class, and position that class absolutely within your parent element. That will make the property the same across each of your planets, no z-index needed. You'll need to play around in order to get everything lined up the way you want, trial and error.

```
<div class="overlay"><img src="planet.png"/></div>
<div class="overlay"><img src="clouds.png"/></div>
<div class="overlay"><img src="texture.png"/></div>
<div class="overlay"><img src="other.png"/></div>​

.overlay{position:absolute;}​
```

Does that help? Let us know how this turns out.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $type = mysql_query("SELECT type FROM planetproperties WHERE planetid='$planetid'");               $type = mysql_fetch_row($type) or die(mysql_error());               $type = $type[0];
 $subtype = mysql_query("SELECT subtype FROM planetproperties WHERE planetid='$planetid'");         $subtype = mysql_fetch_row($subtype) or die(mysql_error());         $subtype = $subtype[0];
 $fulltype = $type.$subtype;
 $cloud = mysql_query("SELECT cloudtex FROM planetproperties WHERE planetid='$planetid'");          $cloud = mysql_fetch_row($cloud) or die(mysql_error());             $cloud = $cloud[0];
 $rad = round($radius / 1000, 0); if($rad > 150){ $rad = 150; }
 $prad = $rad * (1 - $oblateness);
 $prad = round($prad, 0);
 echo "<tr><td style=\"text-align:center;vertical-align:middle\">";
 echo "<div style=\"width:$prad;height:$prad;padding:0;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;float:center;position:relative;background:none\">";
 echo "<img src=\"$fulltype.png\" height=$rad width=$prad style=\"position:absolute;left:0;top:0;z-index:0\">";
 if($cloud){ echo "<img src=\"$cloud.png\" height=$rad width=$prad style=\"position:absolute;left:0;top:0;z-index:10\">"; }
```

:)  Thanks folks.